# Miss-aligned block objects

Tags: html, css

In my footer I have a div that I am trying to center but instead, it is floating on top of the footer. https://codepen.io/k1n64r7hur/pen/MWvaGrP

```
footer {
text-align: center;
background-color: grey;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 1.5em;
display: block;
transition: bottom 0.3s;}   
.test {
float: none;
background-color: blueviolet;
position: absolute;
display: inline-block;
height: 1.5em;
width: 90%;
padding: 0;
bottom: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);}
```

Comment: Please remove `javascript` tag, your question has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: @Maksym Shcherban Well if this is how users are treated I'll be seeking help elsewhere I posted the shortest code snippet possible to my knowledge if I knew exactly what tag was the problem I wouldn't have needed to ask for help!!!

Comment: @paulie_D I tried to include the HTML but the site would not submit the question until i removed it.

Comment: I am sorry you feel this way, I meant no disrespect, but my criticism was appropriate, your question has nothing to do with `javascript`, hence you should not have used this tag.

Answer (score 0):

Height of footer need to be increased.
Usage of translate is pulling the block upwards.

```
footer {
    //text-align: center;
    background-color: grey;
    position: fixed;
    //bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3em;
    //display: block;
    transition: bottom 0.3s;
}   

.test {
    text-align:center;
    //float: none;
    background-color: blueviolet;
    //position: absolute;
    //display: inline-block;
    height: 3em;
    width: 90%;
    padding: 5px 5%;
    //bottom: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    //transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

document.getElementById("footbar").style.bottom = "-3rem";
```

Comment: Thanks, @Godnyl Pula. Why does the translate do this and why did it not have the same effect on my header code?